# How to programmatically get provisioning resources with oim 11g client api

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, identity, identity-management, oim

I'm using the oracle OIM 11g api (in packages oracle.iam). I use the class oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient to get all the OIM client services like UserManager.

I need to find the resources got with the provisioning workflows. Which service can I use? How can I do with the OIM api?

Answer (score 3):

The method below should export all resources into an XML file-

```
public Boolean export() {
    Boolean result = true;
    String export_object="Resource";
    try {
       FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("OIMResources.xml");
       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
       tcExportOperationsIntf moExportUtility = (tcExportOperationsIntf) ioUtilityFactory.getUtility("Thor.API.Operations.tcExportOperationsIntf");
       Collection<RootObject> lstObjects = moExportUtility.findObjects(export_object, "*");
       System.out.println(lstObjects);
       lstObjects.addAll(moExportUtility.getDependencies(lstObjects));
       lstObjects.addAll(moExportUtility.retrieveChildren(lstObjects));
       lstObjects.addAll(moExportUtility.retrieveDependencyTree(lstObjects));
       String s = moExportUtility.getExportXML(lstObjects, "*");    
       out.write(s);
       LOG.info(Resource + "Objects successfully exported");
       out.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occured while exporting OIM object" + Resource, e);
     }
   return result;
 }
```